# How can I stop master from starting itself as a slave (in addition to master) on reboot?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7

In a simple MySQL replication Master-Slave configuration I have a problem where Master tries to connect to itself as a slave on reboot.

So when I restart MySQL on Master, I see errors related to the same server trying to replicate to itself and I have to manually run `mysql -e "STOP SLAVE;"` every time I restart MySQL.

How can I disable slave on master for good?

Here's the relevant portion of `my.cnf`:

```
## Logging
binlog_format                   = mixed
log_bin                         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sync_binlog                     = 1
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#general_log                     = 0
#general_log_file                = /var/log/mysql/general.log
slow_query_log                  = 1
slow_query_log_file             = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time                 = 3
expire_logs_days                = 14

sql_mode                        = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
# sql_mode                        = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

## Replication
server_id                       = 200

## Master Configuration
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_1
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_2
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_3
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_4
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_5
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_6
```

Also, when I run `SELECT * FROM mysql.user;` I don't see the `repl` user that's allegedly a "slave" on Master.

**BUT**, I do see that `localhost` has replication grants:

```
mysql> select Host, User, grant_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv from mysql.user;
+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Host            | User          | grant_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv |
+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| localhost       | root          | Y          | Y               | Y                |
| localhost       | mysql.sys     | N          | N               | N                |
```

Here's an example of the errors I see on Reboot (before I run `STOP SLAVE;` on Master):

```
2016-09-01T15:22:23.845505Z 384 [Note] Access denied for user 'repl'@'192.168.100.200' (using password: YES)
2016-09-01T15:22:23.845761Z 1 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl@192.168.100.200:3306' - retry-time: 30  retries: 8, Error_code: 1045
2016-09-01T15:22:50.191636Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6843ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=15210 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

Apart from this, replication is running fine. Writes to Master show up flawlessly on the real, read-only, Slave.

---

Full `my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
default_character_set           = utf8

[mysqld]
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links                  = 0

## Custom Configuration
skip_external_locking           = 1
skip_name_resolve
open_files_limit                = 20000

## Cache
thread_cache_size               = 16
query_cache_type                = 1
query_cache_size                = 256M
query_cache_limit               = 4M

## Per-thread Buffers
sort_buffer_size                = 32M
read_buffer_size                = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 8M
join_buffer_size                = 2M

## Temp Tables
tmp_table_size                  = 1024M
max_heap_table_size             = 1024M

## Networking
back_log                        = 250
max_connections                 = 512
max_connect_errors              = 100000
max_allowed_packet              = 128M
interactive_timeout             = 1800
wait_timeout                    = 1800
character_set_client_handshake  = FALSE
character_set_server            = utf8mb4
collation_server                = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

### Storage Engines
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
innodb                          = FORCE

## MyISAM
key_buffer_size                 = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 16M

## InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 46G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 64
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 32M
innodb_log_file_size            = 64M
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1

## Logging
binlog_format                   = mixed
log_bin                         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sync_binlog                     = 1
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#general_log                     = 0
#general_log_file                = /var/log/mysql/general.log
slow_query_log                  = 1
slow_query_log_file             = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time                 = 3
expire_logs_days                = 14

sql_mode                        = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
# sql_mode                        = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

## Replication
# Master Server ID:
server_id                       = 200
# Slave Server ID:
# server_id                       = 300

## Master Configuration
# Comment out on Slave
binlog-do-db                    = db_1
binlog-do-db                    = db_2
binlog-do-db                    = db_3
binlog-do-db                    = db_4
binlog-do-db                    = db_5
binlog-do-db                    = db_6

## Slave Configuration
# Uncomment the following on Slave
# relay-log                       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
# binlog-do-db                    = db_1
# binlog-do-db                    = db_2
# binlog-do-db                    = db_3
# binlog-do-db                    = db_4
# binlog-do-db                    = db_5
# binlog-do-db                    = db_6
# log_slave_updates               = 1
# read_only                       = 1
# slave_skip_errors               = 1062

[mysqld_safe]
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links                  = 0
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Comment: It sounds like you did a `CHANGE MASTER` on the Master, as if you wanted dual-master?

Comment: You can skip the slave start using SKIP_SLAVE_START: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_skip-slave-start

Comment: just run - RESET SLAVE must help;

Answer (score 0):

Since this is MySQL 5.7, you need

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE ALL;
```

Running `STOP SLAVE;` is required because replication is updating `master.info`, `relay-log.info`, and relay logs.

Once stopped, running `RESET SLAVE ALL;` does everything. Why ?

## MySQL 5.5

You needed to do this:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='';
```

and that was all.

## MySQL 5.6

There was a problem with the previous method (does not erase memory structures for replication, the ones that have the host, port, user, password).

With that problem, you had run

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='';
```

and the restart mysqld

Another method would have been

```
STOP SLAVE;
```

Go to the OS, delete `master.info`, and still restart mysqld.

BUMMER !!!

## MySQL 5.7

[`RESET SLAVE ALL;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reset-slave.html) successfully clears up the replication memory structures. `RESET SLAVE;` is not enough. Once you run [`RESET SLAVE ALL;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reset-slave.html), you can run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

```
mysql> show slave status\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```